# How to make HTML email appear pretty on a BlackBerry?

Tags: html, email, blackberry

I have written a system that sends HTML marketing emails to a list of opted-in subscribers.

A significant number of those subscribers are BlackBerry users - and my emails look horrible on them... aside from the layout problems with the smaller screen, the message gets truncated at a certain length, and some images don't get displayed at all.

I am unfamiliar with the eccentricities of BB email - so could you please fill me in on what restrictions BB email has that I need to take into consideration when designing a template for the BB users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sending your email newsletter to a Blackberry**

What can you do?  As a sender, you have a few options:

1. Ask your subscribers to enable HTML email on their Blackberries
2. Create a sub-list of Blackberry users, and send them only plain-text emails
3. Have us a create a "Mobile Version" link at the top of your emails
4. Put your most important text at the top of the email

See the reference:

http://blog.mailoutinteractive.com/post/Your-email-newsletter-on-the-Blackberry.aspx

Comment: Eventually I created a special "mobile version" of the emails - thanks

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions that i ve recieved talking with our graphic designer is keep as less html as possible an stay away from heavy mime types. If its also an all text message then you would be better off.

http://www.mobilestorm.com/company/news/email-marketing-to-blackberrys-usage-formating-rendering-tips/

Found the above link and by looking at it i think thats exactly what you re looking for.

Comment: you wouldn't be able to use jQuery mobile as email clients dont allow javascript?

Comment: i mis interpreted the question. Corrected my answer. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No problem, much better answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Sitepoint book [Create Stunning HTML Mail](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/htmlemail1/) -

[image]

maybe it could help you?

(I'm not affiliated in any way with them)