# Email Rendering with BlackBerry 4 OS

Tags: html, css, blackberry, html-email, newsletter

I am coding html email that renders perfectly in most of the clients , browsers and devices but when i test it for  BlackBerry 4 OS it shows html  source code instead of email , this is my Doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This is how it looks for litmus test [image]

Whats wrong with it  ? will it look  good when it goes to  client's  mobile  ? because it might require some setting but i am not sure about that , so plaese help me with it ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documents for litmus.com, [they say](http://litmus.com/help/testing/general/platforms):

> The table below shows the mobile device and its operating system. We
>   use the native mail application included for each mobile device.
>
> BlackBerry 8900 (Plain Text Previews) BlackBerry OS 4 
>   BlackBerry Curve
>   (HTML Previews)   BlackBerry OS 5

But, there are multiple versions of OS 4.x.  If I remember correctly, [HTML support was added in OS 4.5](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/16606/Managing_content_in_RTF_HTML_format_messages_480147_11.jsp#View_settings_for_HTML_format_messages_480148_11), and displaying HTML emails can be enabled/disabled by the individual **user**, or the BES **administrator**, as shown [in this link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/16606/Managing_content_in_RTF_HTML_format_messages_480147_11.jsp#View_settings_for_HTML_format_messages_480148_11).  So, you do need to make sure HTML email is enabled.

There aren't that many devices left with OS < 4.5 at this point, so you'll have to decide whether you need to worry about them at all.

It might be a good idea to send out an HTML **and** plain text version of your emails, assuming you can control the email content.  From [litmus.com](http://litmus.com/help/email-clients/blackberry-text/bb-html):

> ...a lot of BlackBerry devices in use today are actually showing the
>   plain text version of the email. If no plain text version exists, the
>   HTML code will be shown instead.
>
> If you've used the HTML uploader within Litmus, you've nothing to
>   worry about - we didn't ask you for the plain text version so we have
>   nothing to show. If you've sent in an email you should be sure to
>   include a plain text version as alternative part to your email,
>   otherwise plain text email clients, such as BlackBerry's without HTML
>   support, will show your HTML code.

[See this answer for more recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7090003/119114) on handling HTML email with BlackBerry.